# Perform multi-threading on a python program

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to execute 2 function in the same time,
(im new in python, and development in general)
i tried to create a minecraft server setup assistant :

(the code is in development too)

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import wget
import json
from pathlib import Path

...


def startndstop(x):
    os.chdir(newpath)
    if x == "start":
        start = str("java" + ram() + namejar + " nogui")
        print("Demarrage du serveur", name, "!")
        os.system(str(start))
    elif x == "stop":
        os.system("stop")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Yann Installer")
root.iconbitmap("./minecraft_icon_132202.ico")
root.geometry("640x390")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.configure(bg="#0f800f")
bgimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.gif"))
l = tk.Label(root, image=bgimage)
l.pack()
installbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Installer", command=lambda :threading.Thread(target=install("1.8.3")).start())
installbutton.lift(aboveThis=l)
installbutton.place(x=10, y=10)
startbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Demarrer", command=lambda :threading.Thread(target=startndstop("start")).start())
startbutton.lift(aboveThis=l)
startbutton.place(x=10, y=40)
listeVersion = ttk.Combobox(root, values=versionlist())
listeVersion.current(0)
listeVersion.lift(aboveThis=l)
listeVersion.place(x=80, y=10, width=100)

threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop).start()
threading.Thread(target=startndstop,args=('start',)).start()
```

But when I execute the script , the second thread start only when i close the tkinter window.

edit: now the function are called correctly
Could you help me ?

Comment: There is not enough here to test your problem.

Comment: @Mike-SMT i add some part of the code

Comment: You should not run `tkinter.mainloop()` in child thread.  Just create thread for `startndstop()` and then run `tkinter.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread` is not being called correctly.  You are calling `root.mainloop()` and passing its return value to the threads as `target`, requiring it to run to completion in order to return.  Instead, pass the function object itself as target by removing the parentheses.  The second thread has the same issue, but needs to pass arguments as a separate `args` tuple.

Use this:

```
threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop).start() # start the tkinter interface
threading.Thread(target=startndstop,args=("start",)).start() # start the minecraft server
```

Comment: Thank you, but startndstop() run a minecraft server in the console, Tkinter can't print some information in this it think , and i don't know why ,when the server run, the tkinter window not respond, and if i stop the server, all the program is stopped  ...

Comment: @CalamarRobot I just corrected your thread usage. You may have other problems but I don’t have your whole code to reproduce it